# Выпишите это слова(,) в них нужные буквы расставив

Tags: пунктуация

В этой фразе, которая в учебниках русского даётся, всё время деепричасный оборот с помощью запятой разделяют, однако мне кажется, что это неправильно, так как суть задания заключается в расстановке букв. У Розеталя написано, что, если дееприч. оборот имеет гдавный смысл в предложении, он запятой не разделяется. Тогда правда ли, что в трёх этих предложениях те запятые не нужны? (В них акцент делается не на глагол предложения, а на действие, которое выражает деепричастие.)

1. Вы можете(,) по-английски разговаривая(,) учить немецкому?
2. Являясь мокрой(,)  вы пришли домой?
3. Выпишите это слова(,) в них нужные буквы расставив.

Comment: нужен комментарий по поводу "это слова" - это как?

Comment: и у меня есть сомнения насчет корректности инверсии "в них нужные буквы расставив".

Comment: @Буратино, гдавный смысл в глаголе предложения.

Comment: @shampar мне бы еще догадаться, что такое "главный смысл"... Глагол действия смысловой связки не выражает, то есть нет никакого главного смысла, смысл - это связка, она или есть или её нет. Связки выражаются понятиями или предикатами, а не глаголами действия, иногда глаголами производными от понятий, а глагол действия поставленный в коней создает некоторую таинственность фразы, но смысла в этом скорее нет. "в них нужные буквы сохранив" - можно, потому что от сохранение, "в них нужные буквы расставив" - расставление букв? это что?

Comment: @shampar то есть у слова сохранение - есть значение. А у слова расставление значения нет, потому что это просто действие, либо нужно выдумывать что-то вроде "расставление - это наведение порядка", то есть ассоциировать с понятием, но это уже бредово, потому что все равно предикации нет, либо нужно делать так: "в них нужные буквы расставив по местам". То есть у глагола расставив нет собственного предикативного значения.

Comment: Во втором примере нет образа действия (вопрос "как?" не подходит).

Comment: Чтобы было без запятых, действия должны быть одновременными. Возможно, что здесь: *Выпишите эти слова, **перед этим** расставив в них нужные буквы.*